# Проблема с background

Tags: html, css, background

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - если открывать сайт не на полный экран, то при прокрутке вправо - фона просто нет, не могу понять с чем связано.

```
.firstscreen {
min-height: 800px;
background: url(../img/bg/mainscreen.jpg) center center/cover no-repeat;
padding: 39px 0 62px 0;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такое ощущение, будто какой-то блок просто перекрывает этот Посмотрите в другом месте ошибку, возможно вообще никак с этим болоком она не связана. Как вариант - cltr+shift+i, выбрать стрелку(где-то сверху в появившемся окне будет) и кликнуть по этому блоку

Comment: Добавил скриншоты

Comment: Как видите, на первом скриншоте, который вы добавили, `div` с вашим бэкграундом очень маленький. Значит, по какой-то причине у вас что-то уменьшает его размер до данного. Также, видите на второн скрине что сверху над белым есть пустое место? Попробуйте туда навестись, может тогда хоть определим что за блок мешает -_-

Comment: Еще если окно расширять - то фон растягивается вместе с ним, т.е. фон =размеру окна

Answer (score 0):

```
.firstscreen {
min-height: 800px;
background: url(../img/bg/mainscreen.jpg) center center/cover no-repeat;
padding: 39px 0 62px 0;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

и на фотку тоже 100%